# unable to build OpenH264.lib for windows

Tags: windows, build, openh264

I followed all the instruction mentioned in https://github.com/cisco/openh264 but I am unable to get through. The information is cited in link but its quite confusing.

Answer (score 8):

**Alternative Way:** 

You can build Openh264 using visual studio in windows. Here are the steps..

- i) Download OpenH264 source code provided by cisco (that already you
  mentioned https://github.com/cisco/openh264).
- ii) Now you will find two visual studio compatible projects in
  directory **/OpenH264/codec/build/win32/dec** and
  **/OpenH264/codec/build/win32/enc**.
- iii) You will need to download NASM software from  http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.02/
- iv) Install NASM software on the directory C:\NASM or wherever you like.
- v) Then Add NASM executable path to all these visual studio projects. [image]
- vi) Then You can either select static or dynamic library in general
  options.[image]
- vi) If you are able to perform all these operations successfully,  you will have 5 different .lib or .dll files named **welsdcore, welsdecplus, welsecore, welsencplus, welsvp** and those
  are usable in any visual studio projects.

Now if you want to get openh264 features, just add all these libraries to your project and enjoy. 
Hope it will help you.. :)

Comment: Since it's a few years later I'd like to report that this solution worked with VS 2019.

Comment: RajibTheKing's answer perfectly worked. But I get a warning message that caused me to try a few things before I decided to take the risk. I hope this helps someone else and save their time. - When you try to open the **OpenH264** solution in **VS2013** or above, you will get a message of an *irreversible* upgrade. Simply proceed. - follow RajibTheKing`s answer - Build the solution to get the dll files you need

Comment: for openh264 console encoder one needs to build WelsEncCore, WelsEncPlus, WelsVP libraries and then encConsole, the exe-file is generated at bin\x64\Release\encConsole.exe

Answer (score 1):

I also had some difficulty building openh264 on Windows using the recommended mingw approach.

In my case `make` crashed for all configurations I tried:

```
bash -c "make OS=msvc  ARCH=x86_64 USE_ASM=No BUILDTYPE=Debug clean"
bash -c "make OS=msvc  ARCH=x86_64 USE_ASM=No BUILDTYPE=Debug"
  0 [main] make 3888 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
564 [main] make 3888 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
  0 [main] make 5448 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
561 [main] make 5448 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
copying dll files to destination folder...
FullDestDir is E:\projects\openh264\bin\x64\Debug
current dir is:
E:\projects\openh264
DestDir is bin/x64/Debug
cp: cannot stat `openh264.dll': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `openh264.lib': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `openh264.pdb': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `codec_unittest.exe': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `h264enc.exe': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `h264dec.exe': No such file or directory
 BuildDebugFlag   =1
 BuildReleaseFlag =0
 BuildDebugInfo   ="build debug--failed"
 BuildReleaseInfo =NULL
 aBuildFlagList is 1  0
 ReturnCode is 1
```

I resorted to converting the existing solution/projects (VS2008) to VS2013 and linking/building with the created .lib files.

You can find the solutions in `{openh264_dir}\codec\build\win32\enc` and `{openh264_dir}\codec\build\win32\dec`.
Building the solution will create .libs and .dlls in `{openh264_dir}\bin\Win32\Release`

To link to the lib, you need to link to `welsenc.lib`.

When running, you need to have both the `welsenc.dll` and `welsvp.dll` in your application directory. So far it seems to have worked fine for my usage.
I'm assuming that building the decoder will be similar.